# Can't add password to new ssh server host (Permission denied, please try again.)

Tags: ssh, mysql, ssh-tunnel

i use `ssh clie@127.2.0.1` to add new ssh server ip address as shown [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) for **Mysql** multi-devide connection. This is the first time i create ssh with openssh.
But when i enter password (completely new for first time), it shows this error `Permission denied, please try again`. I completely do not understand what happens, if the password is wrong, where can I get the password?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such instructons cointaining `ssh clie@127.2.0.1` from provided link
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui

**Check you command carefully.**

You can only access the machine using an account that exists on the machine with OpenSSH Server installed on it.

Try
`ssh username@localhost` locally or `ssh username@server_ip` from remote host.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest please go through all sub and same level pages of windows ssh https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview . I guess issue is you are trying with password authentication which need some more work in case of windows or AD etc. (Might be some registry related changes)

I am not sure if you setup ssh correctly I can suggest you should try ket based authentication mentioned here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement.

In case of any issue kindly append more logs to your question.